# Изменение префаба объекта после его создания

Tags: c#, unity3d

Известно, что скрипты в Unity работают только если привязаны к объекту, которые находится на сцене. Вопрос: как изменить префаб объекта (игрока) после его появления? Изначально игрок не имеет префаба, ибо он зависит от выбора пользователя. После появления он должен остаться игроком (принадлежать классу Player), но иметь текстуру, свойства и коллайдер выбранного пользователем префаба.

Comment: может добавлять префаб в потомки к Player?

Comment: И как это поможет? Игрок как был пустым объектом при появлении, так и останется.

Comment: а обязательно, что бы скрипт выбора игрока был именно на игроке? Почему не вынести это в отдельную сущность, тогда проблемы не будет

Comment: Так скрипт создания игрока и висит на игровой карте. И с помощью Instantiante добавляет объект Player на позицию объекта PlayerSpawn.

Comment: У меня имеется 9 вариантов того, кем может стать игрок. Насколько правильно будет создать наследника для каждого и для игрока создавать его? Он будет иметь идентичные свойства.

Comment: Инстанцируйте необходимый префаб, а затем добавьте `AddComponent<ВашТип>()` необходимый игроку скрипты.

Comment: Хорошо, а как передать игроку коллайдер префаба?

Comment: Классический пример надобности ScriptableObject'ов